# Project out of date - do not show this dialog again - and build or not build?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, desktop-bridge

In the following dialog which I get when running a Centennial app,

[image: project out of date image]

what does "do not show this dialog again" mean?

> Don't show and *don't* build

Or

> Don't show and *do* build

Comment: Suggestion to UI designers of similar logic: When the checkbox is checked, the button captions should change from "Yes" and "No" to "Always" and "Never"

Comment: @Silvermind pressing Cancel just means don't do anything. no settings are changed, no build is started.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's good, but not enough. Because a user might not notice that because they already read those buttons' texts. I think that the "do not show..." text should be "remember action for the future" or something like that.

Comment: @ispiro: Yes, that's valuable.  Best is to do both.

Comment: @St.Pat I forgot to put the sarcasm tag there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have "Do not show this dialog again" checked, it remembers the choice you make.

If you press Yes while the check box is checked, it will be

> Don't show and *do* build

If you press No while the check box is checked, it will be

> Don't show and *don't* build

The setting that is changed based on your choice is located in the Tools->Options menu.

Go to the "Projects and Solutions" group, and choose the "Build and Run" page.

The first dropdown box, "On Run, when projects are out of date", will show what action is taken when you try to run when projects are out of date.

"Prompt to build" will show the dialog in your question. The other two options are self-explanatory, Always or Never build.

An extra note, if you press Cancel on the dialog, then nothing is done. No settings are changed, no build is started, and the out of date project output is not launched. It's like the dialog never opened in the first place.

Comment: Cancel: No settings are changed, no build is done, **and the out of date project output is not launched**